# Google Translate API: glossary not considered when using translate_document (translate_v3, Python library)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-translation-api, glossary

I am using Google Translate APItranslate_v3, Python library.

Translating text with `translate_text` works pretty fine. Terms that have been specified in a glossary are considered correctly in the target text.

Sample code snippet:

```python
trans_response = client.translate_text(
    request={
        "parent": parent,
        "contents": [source_text],
        "mime_type": "text/plain", 
        "source_language_code": google_source_lang,
        "target_language_code": google_target_lang,
        "glossary_config": glossary_config,
    }
)
```

Now, I modified my code to translate documents with `translate_document`. Unfortunately, in this case, the glossary is not considered in the target text, although the glossary, glossary_config etc. have been setup exactly in the same way as with the above shown text translation. The logs show that the glossary has been created, and there are not other errors. I get a translated document, bu the glossary is not considered.

Sample code snippet:

```python
trans_response = client.translate_document(
    request={
        "parent": parent,
        "document_input_config": document_input_config,
        "source_language_code": google_source_lang,
        "target_language_code": google_target_lang,
        "glossary_config": glossary_config,
    }
)
```

I already tried several source and target combinations and various document formats. The result is always the same. Works fine with plain text translation (translate_text), but not with document translation (translate_document) - then the glossary is not considered in the translated documents.

Answer (score 0):

I need to use the response attribute `glossary_document_translation` instead of `document_translation`.